# Unable to start docker - httpd (pid 1) already running

Tags: apache, docker

I have hosted one docker with PHP in a shared server of our office environments. Previously it was working fine without any issue. All the users were able to access the site via port forwarding to 8080. Here is my docker file details -

```
# Choose Repo from Docker Hub
FROM centos:latest

# Provide details of maintainer
MAINTAINER ritu

#Install necessary software
RUN yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
RUN yum -y install yum-utils
RUN yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
RUN yum -y install php php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo php-devel php-pear make gcc systemtap-sdt-devel httpd unzip postfix
RUN export PHP_DTRACE=yes
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv -f composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
COPY phpinfo.php /var/www/html/
COPY php.ini /var/www/
COPY httpd.conf /var/www/
RUN cp -f /var/www/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/
COPY *.rpm /var/www/

#Install & Configure OCI for PHP
COPY oci8-2.0.12.tgz /
RUN tar -xvf oci8-2.0.12.tgz
RUN yum -y localinstall /var/www/*.rpm --nogpgcheck
COPY client.sh /etc/profile.d/
RUN chmod +x /etc/profile.d/client.sh
RUN cp -f /var/www/php.ini /etc/
COPY php_oci8_int.h oci8-2.0.12/
COPY Log_Check.zip /
RUN unzip Log_Check.zip
RUN cp -a -R /Log_Check/* /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /oci8-2.0.12
RUN phpize
RUN ./configure --with-oci8=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64 
RUN cp -f /usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64/*.h /oci8-2.0.12/include/ 
RUN make 
RUN make install
RUN ls /var/www/html/
RUN rm -rf /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid

#Expose necessary ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 1521
EXPOSE 25

#Provide Entrypoint
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd"]
```

Suddenly one of my friend added another docker with same port 8080 in the same server. After that my docker got stopped. with below error -

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd (pid 1) already running
```

After several hours of googling and after trying lots of commands, I found that its easy to remove the entire container as well as images from the server. Hence I removed all containers with `docker rm` followed by image deletion with `docker rmi`. Again i have recreated the docker image on my local system (its working here) and transferred to server. Again I tried to run the docker. But faced same issue again.

Unable to find out the cause & solution. Need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first remove `ENTRYPOINT` from your `Dockerfile` and just use:

```
CMD [ "/usr/sbin/httpd", "-X" ]
```

the warning regarding `AH00558` is comming from your configuration and it i complaining about you do not use `www.test.com` you can ignore that for now and apache will still working. if you want to read more see [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername)

Comment: As per your suggestion I have removed these lines -
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd"]
and added this - 
CMD [ "/usr/sbin/httpd", -D", "FOREGROUND"]

Then I ran 
docker build c:\docker -t logcheck:v1

Docker builded successfully. But while trying to run, its throwing below error - 
C:\docker>docker logs e7c361bc0728
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Should be `"-D"` not `-D"`. The error message is pretty self explanatory: `I was looking for " and I didn't find it`